# SWIG : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fact'

Tags: python, c, swig

I am studying how to use **swig** to make a C expansion for my python code.And I use the code I get from website as example.
Here is my code:

*example.c*

```
 #include <time.h>
 double My_variable = 3.0;

 int fact(int n) {
     if (n <= 1) return 1;
     else return n*fact(n-1);
 }

 int my_mod(int x, int y) {
     return (x%y);
 }
```

*example.h*

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H_
#define EXAMPLE_H_

 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);

#endif
```

*example.i*

```
%module example
 %{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "example.h"
 %}

%#include "example.h"
```

*Makefile*

```
all:
    rm -f *.so *.o *_wrap.* *.pyc
    swig -python example.i
    gcc -c -fPIC example_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7
    gcc -shared  example_wrap.o -o _example.so

clean:
    rm -f *.so *.o *_wrap.* *.pyc
```

*test.py*

```
import example

print str(example.fact(2))
```

The test.py is used to check if the expansion works.But when I run the test.py , it output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print str(example.fact(2))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fact'
```

Here is the output when I use dir(example):

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_example', '_newclass', '_object', '_swig_getattr', '_swig_property', '_swig_repr', '_swig_setattr', '_swig_setattr_nondynamic']
```

What's the reason of this output appears?

If I want to the programme run successfully,how should I do?

Comment: Perhaps: "gcc -shared -o _example.so  example_wrap.o" can do the trick, usually what is linked to the library is put after the .so.

Comment: @Tony It still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, then maybe "gcc -shared -Wl,-soname, _example.so  -o _example.so example_wrap.o", if it is not properly linked. Sorry if it does not help, I don't use SWIG but I had similar problems using boost.python and they were related to compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to replace as below:

```
%#include "example.h"
```

by

```
%include "example.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Reference](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/%7Egfrancis/illimath/windows/aszgard_mini/bin/SWIG-1.3.21/Doc/Manual/Python.html)

Try changing the Makefile to

```
%module example
%{
   #include "example.h" 
%}
int fact(int n);
```

I've assumed you have only one method to export